# prepend zero onto day

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loop that is creating a drop down of 31 days. days 1-9 need a zero prepended onto them such as 01-09 to make sure sql server does not throw an error. I rather do this in the jquery then later on.

```
for (i = 1; i < 32; i++)
{
    if (i > 9)
    {
        $('#daypicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    } else {
        $('#daypicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
}
```

so I need 01-31, not 1-31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer - inside the loop:

```
var str = (i >= 10) ? i : '0' + i;
```

then use `str` instead of `i` in the `.val()` and `.html()` calls, having removed the `if / else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Does this not work for some reason:

```
} else {
    $('#daypicker').append($('<option />').val('0' + i).html('0' + i));
}
```

Comment: sure, it works, but it breaks the "don't repeat yourself" principle.  The right thing to do is obtain the correct displayed value, and then call the functions _once_ without the "else" clause.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but not sure Primetime did. I answered in a way that I assume fits his programming style.

Comment: This is how I was trying to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1; i < 32; i++)
{
   var str = (i < 10 ) ? "0" + i : i;
   $('#daypicker').append($('<option />').val(str ).html(str));
}
```